# Sharepoint online list specify column width and row height with json

Tags: json, formatting, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am trying to format a SharePoint Online modern list using json and I couldn't find a way to specify a custom column width and row height. 
So far it looks like this
and users have to manually adjust column width.

[image]

My json code is this:

```html
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "width": "200px",
    "white-space": "nowrap",
    "padding-left": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, ' ') == 1, '', if(indexOf(@currentField, ' ') == 3, '20px', '40px'))"
  }
}
```

Also, I couldn't find a way to make the list more compact. The default row height is too high.

How can I specify column width and row height?

I am new to SharePoint so any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the column width and row height, you need to add the property "width" and "height" in your json code.

For exmaple:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
     "min-height":"1em",
    "height": "1em",
    "width": "100px"
  }
}
```

Please refer to this article for more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The properties didn't worked for column format, but worked for view format. I managed to solve the problem with a custom view format.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the Above. But after adding this to the column format. When I try to open the items, they are overlapping with each other.

Here is the JSON that added:

```
{  
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",  
  "elmType": "div", 
  "style": {  
    "font-size": "12px"  ,
    "min-height":"1em",
    "height": "1em",
    "width": "100px"
  },  
  "txtContent": "@currentField",  
  "customCardProps": {  
    "formatter": {  
      "elmType": "div",  
      "txtContent": "@currentField",  
      "style": {  
        "font-size": "12px",  
        "color": "green",  
        "padding": "5px"  
        
      }  
    },  
    "openOnEvent": "hover",  
    "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",  
    "isBeakVisible": true,  
    "beakStyle": {  
      "backgroundColor": "white"  
    }  
  }  
}
```

[Overlapping sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn49v.png)

[Second overlapping sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0dmK.png)